# add file(lob) to oracle db using stored procedure and codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, oracle11g

I'm trying to save a PDF file directly to db oracle (not a path) by stored_procedure function in codeigniter framework

i modified the _execute() function at oci8_driver.php file and add this

```
protected function _execute($sql)
{
    $this->stmt_id = FALSE;
    $this->_set_stmt_id($sql);
    $blob=FALSE;
    $myarray=array();
    $myarray = $this->binds;

  if (is_array($myarray)) {
  foreach ($myarray as $value)     {     
  if ($value['type'] ===  113 )
   {

$this->lob = oci_new_descriptor($this->conn_id, OCI_D_LOB);

     $blob=TRUE;
  }  }
 ...........
 ..................
 .....

    $exec_worked = ociexecute($this->stmt_id, $this->_commit);

            if (is_array($myarray)) {    
        foreach ($myarray as $value)     {
           if ($value['type'] ===  113 )
        {
      oci_execute($this->stmt_id, OCI_DEFAULT);

          if($blob)
             {
      $this->lob->savefile($value['value'] );
         oci_commit($this->conn_id);
             }

    }  

 }
```

and modify the _bind_param() function in the same file adding this lines

```
     if ($param['type'] === 113)
          oci_bind_by_name($this->stmt_id , $param['name'], $this->lob,    $param['length'], OCI_B_BLOB);
```

**but the problem is it save files twice** ...i test the procedure itself and the model function all show that it executed one time, i don't know where the duplication occur

is my modification cause the problem and what i should do?

Answer (score 0):

Call `$this->db->simple_query()` instead of `$this->db->query()` and/or `$this->db->stored_procedure()`.